# hm10 with arduino not reading UUID from ibeacon

Tags: arduino, ibeacon, hm-10

Using a hm10 on arduino when sending AT+DISI? returns something like

```
+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:CAD9D2E2AE09:-071OK
```

which has no UUID and it is impossible to know whether it is a real ibeacon. All around BT devices are returned  (even mobile phones and printers). How do I properly filter for  ibeacons?

Last FW was uploaded to hm10 (V701).

Answer (score 0):

You must filter for beacons at a higher level. The response to the `AT+DISI?` command will give you a list of all Bluetooth LE advertisements scanned.  Some of these will be iBeacon devices and some of them not.

An example of an iBeacon detection will look something like this, always starting with 4C000215:

```
+DISC:4C000215:2F234454CF6D4A0FADF2F4911BA9FFA6:00000001AC:0CF3EE041CCE:-052OK
```

In the above output, the 2F234454CF6D4A0FADF2F4911BA9FFA6:00000001 byte sequence refers to the UUID, major and minor:

Proximity UUID: 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6
Major: 0000
Minor: 0001

The above example was discovered after sending these commands:

```
AT+ROLE1
AT+IMME1
AT+RESET
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679554/1461050) for more info on how the above detection was set up.

Comment: Sorry but the problem is that i do not receive those params and i'm setting role1 and imme1. All of them are 0's as you can see on my example: +DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:CAD9D2E2AE09:-071OK

Comment: Are you sure your beacon is transmitting?  Try an iOS or Android detection app.

Comment: For sure. ibeacon id's are being read from android app (ble scanner) and mac address is being read by hm10 properly...but just receving mac address as shown. UUID and other params are not sent.